# EWS appointment time intervals

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, appointment

This question probably has a very easy solution!

At work we're using Exchange 2010, and a co-developer insists that the web services only bring back a range of appointment slots that are 30 minutes long.

We really need the times to be in increments of 10- or 15- minutes, but he maintains that there is no way in EWS that the increments can be shortened.

Is this true? and if not, how can the time increments be shortened?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about using the GetUserAvailibility operation in EWS ? You can adjust the Interval using the MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes property see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580719(v=exchg.150).aspx . The default is 30 minutes but it can be between 6 and 1440 minutes.

Cheers
Glen